# Firefox Displays Page as Blank

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox is displaying a website that I coded as completely blank, please help!

The website in question is [www.elderandwild.com](http://www.elderandwild.com). When I first made the site, I tested it on Firefox and it worked just fine. It has had a few updates since then but I don't know at what point it stopped working and I have no idea what is wrong. It works fine on webkit browsers including iOS.

[Screenshot of Network Inspector Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfK5s.png)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: I think you have some css errors and firefox can't handle them. Have a look at the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elderandwild.com%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is my first time using Stack Overflow and everyone who has responded has helped me fix the problem and learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Making `overflow: initial` is working fine.

```
html, body {
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Comment: Phantom, you are a hero. Thank you.

Comment: I've upvoted but because I'm new it doesn't display. Thanks again though!